# ASP.NET : Add a number to local variable in view

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, razor

I know the solution for this should be simple, but I can't figure it out.
When I add a number (for example 2) to page variable, it actually considers it as a string and shows: instead of 3 : 1+2

```
@{
     var page= 1 ;  
 }


<li>@page+2</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression must be evaluated server side so it must be enclosed in parenthesis:

```
<li>@(page+2)</li>
```

If you don't then parser will evaluate server side only first token after <kbd>@</kbd>, `page` will be replaced with its value and you'll have `<li>1+2</li>` HTML text (where, of course, no more evaluation will  be performed).